# Move tag parts via xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Is it possible to transform something like this

```
<tag name="a"/>
<something>
    <endtag name="a"/>
    <tag name="b"/>
</something>
<endtag name="b"/>
```

to this

```
<something>
    <tag name="a"/>
    <endtag name="a"/>
    <tag name="b"/>
    <endtag name="b"/>
</something>
```

via xsl transformation? So I know that `<something>` may or may not get between corresponding `<tag>` and `<endtag>`, which is bad and I have to move it.

UPD:
A bit more info. Suppose we have an input xml, which has 3 types of tags: `<tag>`, `<endtag>` and `<something>`. Our goal is to transform it the way that each, for example, `<tag name="a"/>` becomes `<a>`, `<endtag name="a"/>` becomes `</a>` and `<something>` just stays `<something>`. So with the first piece of XML that I provided it will lead to a not well-formed XML, precisely this:

```
<a>
<something>
    </a>
    <b>
</something>
</b>
```

So I need to make some preparations and move that `<something>` the way that it broadens up and has both `<tag>` and `<endtag>` inside of it and not only one of them.

UPD 2:
1) what we have
2) what is needed
[image]

Comment: I am afraid your question is not well-defined and the example is ambiguous. Please explain the exact rules that need to applied here. Seeing a minimal but **complete** XML input and output would also help. And if you have two possible scenario, show examples for both.

Comment: @michael.hor257k updated

Comment: **1.** You cannot use XSLT to produce an ill-formed XML document. -- **2.**  Your added explanation sounds like to you want to **group** the elements in-between `tag` and `endtag`. That's easy to do if you're using XSLT 2.0 and you can find many similar examples here. I will not post an answer because (a) you still did not provide an input we can work with and (b) I am still mostly guessing what the purpose here is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i can if I transform each `<tag name="a"/>` to `<a>` and each `<endtag name="a"/>` to `</a>`, and this is the problem because this is exactly how i have to transform it

Comment: No, you cannot do that with XSLT - nor do you need to. XSLT works on the source **tree**, not on the representation of the tree as XML. The result of the transformation is also a tree, and only at the end is the tree serialized to an XML document. You just need to change the way you think about this, then it becomes easy.

Comment: @michael.hor257k i drew a tree for you

Comment: I am afraid that too is ambiguous. The result could be achieved just by moving the siblings of `smth` so that they become its children. That's completely different from what you said so far. -- And I am sure you have a mistake with the duplicate endtags.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yup, corrected the mistake. You almost got it right, the only addition is that i need to move only the first previous and the first following siblings and not all the siblings

Comment: I am afraid this is still very confusing, but I have posted an answer that does  exactly that, at least AFAICS.

Answer (score 0):

> i need to move only the first previous and the first following siblings

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <tag name="a"/>
    <tag name="b"/>
    <something>
        <endtag name="c"/>
        <tag name="d"/>
    </something>
    <endtag name="e"/>
    <endtag name="f"/>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="something">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="preceding-sibling::tag[1]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::endtag[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag[following-sibling::*[1][self::something]] | endtag[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::something]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <tag name="a"/>
  <something>
    <tag name="b"/>
    <endtag name="c"/>
    <tag name="d"/>
    <endtag name="e"/>
  </something>
  <endtag name="f"/>
</root>
```